# How to run csh script in bash shell

Tags: bash, makefile, csh

My default shell is bash in Ubuntu 14.04. I have a csh script file named `clean.sh` with the following make command:

```
#! /bin/csh -f
make -f commande.make del
```

And `commande.make` has

```
CKHOME=../CHEMKIN/DATA_BASES
LIN_DATA=${CKHOME}/LIN_FILES/
LINK_CKTP=${CKHOME}/LINK_CKTP_FILES/
#-----------------------------------------------------
include schema_cinetique.make
LINKFILE=${NAME}_LINK
LINKTPFILE=${NAME}_LINKTP
LINKFILE_OLD=${NAME_OLD}_LINK
LINKFILE_NEW=${NAME_NEW}_LINK
#-----------------------------------------------------
cplink :    
    ${COPY} ${LINK_CKTP}${LINKFILE} LINK
cplink2 :   
    ${COPY} ${LINK_CKTP}${LINKFILE} LINKZ1
tplink :    
    ${COPY} ${LINK_CKTP}${LINKTPFILE} LINKTPZ1
calcul :
    ${COPY} jobtimp1  LJOBNZ1
    ${COPY} unsteadyf.dat1 DATZ1
del :
    ${DELETE} LINKZ1 LINKTPZ1 LJOBNZ1 DATZ1 SOLASUZ1
```

I opened the terminal and moved to the location and tried

```
./clean.sh
```

or

```
csh clean.sh &
```

or

```
csh -f clean.sh
```

Nothing worked.

I got the following line in the terminal,

```
LINKZ1 LINKTPZ1 LJOBNZ1 DATZ1 SOLASUZ1
make: LINKZ1: Command not found
make: *** [del] Error 127
```

So, how to run `clean.sh` file ?

Comment: What does `Nothing worked` mean? Can you post the error message?

Comment: Your script uses `commande.make`. But your file is named `command.make`.

Comment: @hek2mgl, please check the edited question again with the error

Comment: Try this: `DELETE=rm ./clean.sh`

Comment: @ceving, sorry for the typo. The script and file name is same.  `commande.make`

Comment: I would first try to get it running from the command line, with either `csh clean.s`h` or `tcsh clean.sh`, depending on which CSH-implementation you have installed. Report, whether this works, or what error messages you get. Of course the question is why you want to run it under csh and not simply turn it into a i.e. bash script. The full csh script does not only containt that single line you have posted, does it?

Comment: @user1934428, I tried the `csh clean.sh` command and got `LINKZ1 LINKTPZ1 LJOBNZ1 DATZ1 SOLASUZ1 make: LINKZ1: Command not found make: *** [del] Error 127`. Can you please tell me how to turn Csh script to bash script. The Csh script I posted contains only the single line.

Comment: No need to change anything. Just run it as `bash clean.sh`. You may want to delete/update the initial #! line, if you want. Alternatively, you can also invoke `make` directly from the command line (why do you use a script, if all what it does is just calling `make`???)  However, I have rather the feeling that something is wrong with the Makefile itself, so this is is unrelated to which shell happens to be used to invoke _make_. Unfortunately, your posting is incomplete in this respect, so I can't help here much. It seems that the make variable `DELETE` is empty.

Comment: @hek2mgl, `DELETE=rm ./clean.sh` actually worked without exporting the variables as you mentioned. Can you please clarify a little bit?

Comment: The `export` is not really necessary if you specify it on the same command line as the `make` command. That sets the variable only for the duration of the command's execution. The answer actually tries to explain this; maybe read up on what `export` does if you need a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You are confused. The Csh script contains a single command which actually runs identically in Bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
make -f commande.make del
```

Or, for that matter, the same with `#!/bin/sh`.  Or, in this individual case, even `sh clean.sh`, since the shebang is then just a comment, and the commands in the file are available in `sh` just as well as in `csh`.

Once `make` runs, *that* is what parses and executes the commands in `commande.make`.  `make` is not a "Fortran command", it is a utility for building projects (but the `makefile` named `commande.make` probably contains some instructions for how to compile Fortran code).

In the general case, Csh and Bash are incompatible, but the differences are in the shell's syntax itself (so, the syntax of loops and conditionals, etc, as well as variable assignments and various other shell builtins).

As an aside, Csh command files should probably not have a `.sh` extension, as that vaguely implies Bourne shell (`sh`)  syntax. File extensions on Unix are just a hint to human readers, so not technically important; but please don't confuse them/us.

(As a further aside, nobody should be using `Csh` in 2022. There was a time when the C shell was attractive compared to its competition, but that was on the order of 40 years ago.)

The subsequent errors you are reporting seem to indicate that the `makefile` depends on some utilities which you have not installed. Figuring that out is a significant enough and separate enough question that you should probably ask a new question about that, probably with more debugging details.  But in brief, it seems that `make` needs to be run with parameters to indicate what `NAME` and `COPY` (and probably some other variables) should be. Try with `make -f commande.make COPY=cp DELETE=rm NAME=foobar` for a start, but it's probably not yet anywhere near sufficient.

(I would actually assume that there will be a `README` file or similar to actually instruct you how to use `commande.make` since it seems to have some local conventions of its own.)

Comment: If you are not getting `csh: command not found` it actually worked, and the only problem is that you need to figure out how to run the commands in `commande.make` correctly.

Comment: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/ explains some problems with Csh, and coincidentally provides identical or near-identical `sh` constructs for many of the problematic behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the script is written having portability in mind, i.e. the name of the `cp` and `rm` binaries is kept in variables rather than hard-coding it. My best guess is that this has been done to make it possible to run the script on non UNIX systems, like Windows.

To make it work, export the respective variables before running the script. For the `del` action you are calling, only the `DELETE` variable is needed. It should be set to `rm` which is the command used to remove files on Linux:

```
export DELETE=rm
./clean.sh
```

Note: exporting the variable can also be done in one line when invoking the script, by prepending it to the command line:

```
DELETE=rm ./clean.sh
```

This behaviour is described in the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Environment):

> The environment for any simple command or function may be augmented temporarily by prefixing it with parameter assignments, as described in Shell Parameters. These assignment statements affect only the environment seen by that command.